# SharePoint PowerShell Filtering a List by an Array

Tags: 2010, powershell

Let's say I have an array

```
$PermitIDs = "1","2","3","4","5","6","7";
```

I want to find where these are in the array field of a list, kinda like so:

```
$ListItems= $List.Items | where-object {$_["ID"] -contains $PermitIDs};
```

This doesn't seem to want to work in PowerShell (returns no results), But I can't find the way of doing this.
Anyone ever managed this?

I am on an older SharePoint 2010 if it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to have the array first and then the specific ID you are looking for?  They way you have it it appears that you are checking to see if the ID field of a list item contains an entire array of numbers, which of course it does not.  So something like `where-object {$PermitIDs -contains $_["ID"]}` ?

Comment: Thanks @DylanCristy you nailed it.  Feel free to answer that below and I'll give you some more points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you want to have the array first and then the specific ID you are looking for?

The way you have it, it appears that you are checking to see if the ID field of a list item contains an entire array of numbers, which of course it does not. So it should be something like:

```
where-object {$PermitIDs -contains $_["ID"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to filter the list items who has same ID as in specific array of ID's.

Try using below code:

```
$ListItems= $List.Items | where-object {$PermitIDs -contains $_["ID"]};
```

Source:

[Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell6)

Comment: Ok ethics question here since you're a moderator Ganesh, since Dylan answered this the same way in comments, does he get a chance to actually answer this and earn Points, or shall I say you beat him to the punch and give you the points...

Comment: @tekiegreg it's not only about points. You got your problem solved that's more important. I should have read the comments before answering.